# How to get UTC equivalent for my local time in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

My machine is on PDT and if I say DateTime.Now, then I will get a local time which is say equivalent to Sep-18th 2012 6:00:00 AM. I want to get UTC equivalent for this datetime instance. UTC time will be 7 hours ahead Of PDT and 8 hours ahead of PST. I want to consider daylight saving automatically.

Any idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

To convert an existing DateTime, *assuming it has time zone information*, you can use [DateTime.ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx).  If you get the DateTime instance using e.g.

```
var localNow = DateTime.Now;  // Has timezone info
```

it will have time zone information.  If you create it e.g. using a tick count, it will not contain timezone information unless you explicitly supply it.

```
var unspecifiedNow = new DateTime(someTickCount); // No timezone info
```

It is worth mentioning that timezone handling in .NET is not optimal.  You may wish to have a look at [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) (a project by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)) if you need to do anything elaborate involving time zones.

Answer (score 9):

Use DateTime.[ToUniversalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) Method.

Comment: for the special case of now this isn't the because under the hood .net is going to convert `DateTime.UtcNow` to local time, so doing `ToUniversalTime` will do 2 conversions instead of 0.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to convert any date from your time-zone to UTC do this:

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(myLocalDateTime)
```

If you want to convert it back from UTC:

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(myUtcDateTime)
```