# Get the corresponding starting local hour in utc c#

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

How to get a UTC hour for the local time.
For example, local time in Asia/Kolkata is 14:00:00 how to get the corresponding starting UTC hour 08:0:0(actual value is 8:30:00)? .im searching a global solution for all timezone.

Comment: What is the data you are having? I mean DateTime object or string input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483084/how-to-get-utc-equivalent-for-my-local-time-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Hour` method will help you

Here you find the corresponding documentation: [`System.Datetime.ToUniversalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: what is `dateTime` ?

Comment: variable, which stores any local time, in example it's _local time in Asia/Kolkata is 14:00:00_

Comment: sorry .im bit confused with hour.Actually i m searching for
 14:00:00 how to get the corresponding starting UTC hour 08:0:0(actual value is 8:30:00)?

Comment: @vct You can substract the minutes value, if its required